# A question on Hochschild cohomology

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hochschild-cohomology

Given a nonsemisimple symmetric algebra B and a non-selfinjective algebra A (all algebras are finite dimensional over a field and connected).
Can A and B have isomorphic Hochschild-cohomology rings?

Comment: You want $A$ and $B$ connected, presumably?

Comment: yes, they should be connected. I added it to the question.

Comment: As a motivation: I think if the answer to the question is "no", this would give a proof of the Tachikawa conjecture. But I have close to zero experience with Hochschild cohomology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are examples of non-semisimple algebras with trivial Hochschild cohomology: for example, the path algebra $C$ of a quiver whose underlying graph is a tree.

Also, for finite dimensional algebras, the Hochschild cohomology algebra of a tensor product of algebras is the tensor product of their Hochschild cohomology algebras.

So take any symmetric algebra $B$, and let $A=B\otimes_kC$ for $C$ as above.